# Qt can't compile

Tags: c++, qt

I am new with QT and c++. So I do this tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QMainWindow_QAction_ImageViewer.php)

I copied everything, but qt can't compile this.

```
    //imageviewer.cpp
#include "imageviewer.h"
#include "ui_imageviewer.h"

ImageViewer::ImageViewer(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ImageViewer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QImage image("C:/TEST/GoldenGate.png");
    ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}

ImageViewer::~ImageViewer()
{
    delete ui;
}

//imageviewer.h
#ifndef IMAGEVIEWER_H
#define IMAGEVIEWER_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScrollArea>

namespace Ui {
class ImageViewer;
}

class ImageViewer : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ImageViewer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ImageViewer();

private:
    QLabel *imageLabel;
    QScrollArea *scrollArea;
    Ui::ImageViewer *ui;

};

#endif // IMAGEVIEWER_H
```

And got this:
'class Ui::ImageViewer' has no member named 'imageLabel'

I can't understand why it doesnt't see this variable.

Comment: Do you mean to use `ui->imageLabel` which you defined in your form file or `imageLabel` which you define in `ImageViewer`? I think you simply want to change `ui->imageLabel` to `imageLabel` inside `ImageViewer::ImageViewer`.

Comment: Did you put a label and name it `imageLabel` in the form editor for your `ImageViewer` class?

Comment: `Ui::ImageViewer`, and `ImageViewer` are 2 different classes, and `Ui::ImageViewer` doesn't have much of a definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your Ui::ImageViewer is not complete .. it does not have 'imageLabel' added. Open the form in design mode and add QLabel, name it 'imageLabel' and try again.

Otherwise, follow tutorial to the end, it adds the QLabel 'imageLabel' dynamically in imageview.cpp.

```
// imageview.cpp

#include "imageviewer.h"
#include "ui_imageviewer.h"

ImageViewer::ImageViewer(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ImageViewer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    imageLabel = new QLabel;
    imageLabel->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

    scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Image Viewer"));
    resize(500, 400);
}
```